# DQS and Azure SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, data-quality-services

So I know that DQS isn't available in Azure, at least not yet. I was wondering though, is it possible to link an on-prem instance that holds the information to an Azure processing task and create a hybrid?

I just wondered if this has been tried/people knew if it could be before I tried anything myself.

Thanks